# how to call route with value from link using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

```
row.append($("<td>" +"<a href='{{url("Edit"), ["id"=> "rowData.ord_id"]}}' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Edit | "+"</a>" +"<a href='' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Delete"+"</a>" + "</td>"));
```

as you can see i am trying to call route with value, but above line giving error
my controller will be like this:

```
 Route::get('Editcat/{id}','ProductController@gocatedit');
```

please correct the jquery code.

Answer (score 3):

Best you can do is to create URL manually, something like:

```
'<a href="/Editcat/' + rowData.ord_id + '">Edit</a>'
```

Instead of:

```
{{url("Edit"), ["id"=> "rowData.ord_id"]}}
```

Never use Blade to build JS.

Comment: Well, I gave you an idea, you should implement it to your app. You can run `php artisan route:list` which will show you all working routes. Choose route you're interested in and create URL manually for this route.

Comment: can i call route like this in jquery <a href="<?php echo 'Edititem/'.$value->item_id; ?>"

Comment: It's a bad practice. Your JS code shouldn't be dynamically created (with PHP). It should be static and minified. Just use JS to create URL, it's pretty easy task. Use something like this to debug: `console.log('<a href="/Editcat/' + rowData.ord_id + '">Edit</a>')`.

Comment: if i change script like this '<a href='deletecart/1'' is working